# Action Bar null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the title of an Action Bar but I am having the null pointer exception, I am not very expert so I don't really know how to catch the exception or do it properly, basically this is the line I am having problem with:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch (id){

        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        case R.id.profile_ic:
            openItemManager();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void openItemManager(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemManagerActivity.class);
    //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blitzar.stiktag" >

<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ItemManagerActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_item_manager" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_banner_orange" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is the activity_main XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.blitzar.stiktag.Activities.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tag"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/found"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lost"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the log if that is any help:

```
08-12 21:37:39.113      450-450/com.blitzar.stiktag E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL     EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.blitzar.stiktag, PID: 450
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.blitzar.stiktag/com.blitzar.stiktag.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
        at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual  method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference
        at  com.blitzar.stiktag.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: yet another ... use it after super.onCreate/setContentView

Comment: post your error logs

Comment: Are you using AppCompatActivity or ActionBarActivity?

Comment: The class extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using android.app.ActionBar. So you have to do the following

1. Remove the import statement *import android.app.ActionBar;*
2. Now import the **support ActionBar** class using *import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;*
3. Then **copy/paste** the cody given below.
4. ***Done***

getSupportActionBar() is used when your class extends from **support library**, ie **AppCompatActivity** or **ActionBarActivity**. In that case the proper way to get reference to ActionBar is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange);
    }
```

The Action Bar follows the material design guidelines and uses a Toolbar. As you can read here:

> The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is
>   discouraged on API 21 devices and newer. If you would like an
>   application icon, you can use the method setLogo().

Comment: Thanks for help, but still not working, is giving me the same warning

Comment: Are you getting warning or error? Did your app crash, when you ran the code?

Comment: yes the app is crashing I just posted the log thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer. You are using ActionBarActvity, but the import statement of ActionBar is not from the support version. So follow the steps I've given above.

Comment: Thanks I am trying still gives me warning but the app is not crashing, however I cannot see any logo on the title :(, also any idea why i am getting this message: android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is deprecated?

Comment: Because it's deprecated, meaning a better version is available, and you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: So should I use just activity?

Comment: You should be using AppCompatActivity!.

Comment: @OP since my solution resolved your doubts, I guess it needs to be upvoted, and marked as solved.

Answer (score 5):

Please use the actionbar only after setting the views.

First use these,

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

then this,

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange);
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for updating the question. Now the problem is obvious.

See, you are using the `ActionBarActivity` class which has long been deprecated. You should be seeing a strike-through in Android Studio. It is RECOMMENDED to use `AppCompatActivity`

Just extend AppCompatActivity and use `getSupportActionBar()`. You will not be getting any `NullPointerException` anymore.

If you have any problem displaying the icon, please try this,

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | 
   ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
   actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: I use to have it that way, but still throwing an exception, I tried again but nothing changes

Comment: Please post your XML layout.

Comment: Thanks I have posted the android manifest, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I said the XML layout, namely activity_main

Comment: The layout is okay. You need to post more code from your Activity for me to debug.

Comment: any idea of what is happening?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Please let me know if there is any more problem?

Comment: It is true what you said, thank you, it was the android studio which by default extended ActionBarActivity, now my logo still not changing but at least I am not getting the null pointer

Comment: Thanks, but not working if i initialize action Bar in null it crashes again

Answer (score 2):

Before initializing any view please call [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
 actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange);
```

Please update your style.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">


</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">  </style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer, I already tried either way but still throwing exception

Comment: your class extends what ?? Actionbaractivity or other

Comment: extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated ,use Activity or AppCompatActivity

Comment: use getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange); for Activity/ActionBarActivity

Comment: I tried that as well, but it still gives me the warning and the app crashes, Im getting message when I put mouse over the extends ActionBarActivity which i don't know what it is but it says: 
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity is deprecated

Comment: can you post your logcat ,For my opinion avoid using ActionBarActivity

Comment: I don't have much experience so when I added a theme for the layout i added holo light dark action bar so it just automatic extended actionbaractivity

Comment: no problem . use Activity .i think you using eclipse

Comment: I posted the log, I am using android Studio

Comment: @Juancadiyjohndiy Okay.please check my edited answer. i hope it will help you

Comment: just extends Activity . Give feedback

Comment: if i just extend activity the does not even show the action bar

Comment: then..you should use AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 1):

You have called

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange);
```

before  initilizing your activity's view. so at that time your actionbar is null.

you must call

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

first then your actionbar method.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.profile_banner_orange);
```

Comment: Please explain your solution to future questioners.